# Stub with # in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

The tutorial on [Listing 5.15](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-partials) uses the term  "stubbed out the URLs with `#` for now". I'm not sure what `#` does here.

It says that Rails usually writes URLs conventionally using named routes like `about_path`, instead of `#`. What's the purpose of putting `#` first then putting named routes as compared to the alternative of adding the named routes directly?

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    by <a href="http://www.michaelhartl.com/">Michael Hartl</a>
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About",   '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", '#' %></li>
      <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` is an empty HTML anchor fragment. I've noticed it's quite common practice to use it in page mockups for links that should appear, but have no target yet.

> Note: You can use `href="#top"` or the empty fragment `href="#"` to link to the top of the current page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: So is this a feature of HTML5 to allow us to put an empty route that actually passes the test cases, only to come back later and update the view?

Comment: Yes, exactly it is

Comment: Its a much older practice that predates HTML5 by about a decade. Its commonly used when you have a javascript handler for a link as well.